# What status do pods go into during HorizontalPodAutoscaler scaling down

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

I was reviewing some of the HorizontalPodAutoscaler docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/ along with several other resources and I haven't been able to identify what pod status occurs during when HPA is actually scaling down. I'd imagine this goes from `running` to `terminated` but there's no mention of this in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HPA will change the Deployment's `replicas:` value, and which will change the `replicas:` value in the current ReplicaSet, which will cause one of the Pods to get deleted.  From the Pod's point of view this is the same as any other situation when a Pod gets deleted, including manual scale-in or updating the Deployment spec.

The "status" column in the `kubectl get pods` output should match the [Pod phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase), except that `Terminating` and `Terminated` are special values.  If the Pod shuts down immediately I would expect it to jump from `Running` to `Terminated`, but it might wait in `Terminating` if it takes some time to do its cleanup after receiving the termination signal.